# Rails Active Support: Calculate last week from a specific date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activesupport

I need to calculate the last week from a specific date.

I know that Rails has `1.week.ago.beginning_of_week` and `1.week.ago.end_of_week` methods but i think those calculations only work based on the current time.

Is there a way to create **any** Time object (not just the current) and calculate the previous week using a similar approach?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add/subtract `Time` (or `Date`; or `DateTime`):

```
time = Time.parse("01/23/1995") #Valid Time object of any time in past/future

week_ago = time - 1.week

beginning_of_week_ago = week_ago.beginning_of_week
end_of_week_ago = week_ago.end_of_week
```